# Could not find artifact org.alfresco:alfresco-super-pom

Tags: pom.xml, alfresco, parent-pom

I want to build the alfresco-repository JAR from source.

I cloned https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-repository and ran the command specified in the [Building](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-repository#building-and-testing) section of the README:

```
$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.alfresco:alfresco-repository:6.21-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.alfresco:alfresco-super-pom:pom:9 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 8, column 13
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The README does not say it, but you have to perform this before (in any directory):

```
git clone git@github.com:Alfresco/alfresco-super-pom.git
cd alfresco-super-pom
mvn install
```

Then alfresco-repository can be built successfully.